# codemirror related css files not getting loaded when using require

Tags: javascript, requirejs, codemirror

I am using require js to load codemirror.

In main.js i have,

```
requirejs.config({
packages: [{
name: “codemirror”,
location: window.siteRootDir + ‘node_modules/codemirror’,
main: “lib/codemirror”
}],
```

And in my actual js file i have this

```
define([
‘codemirror’,
‘codemirror/mode/yaml/yaml’,
‘codemirror/addon/fold/comment-fold’,
‘codemirror/addon/fold/foldgutter’,
‘codemirror/addon/fold/foldcode’,
‘codemirror/addon/lint/lint’,
‘codemirror/addon/lint/yaml-lint’,
```

When the application loads, in the network tab i see the js files are getting loaded but the css files (codemirror.css, lint.css, foldgutter.css) are not loaded.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: https://discuss.codemirror.net/t/codemirror-related-css-files-not-getting-loaded-when-using-require/1896/2

Comment: The above mentioned issed is resolved.

Comment: I now have another issue here.

Comment: The yaml lint depends on js-yaml.
I added this as a npm module and incuded it in main.js as
paths: {
‘js-yaml’: window.siteRootDir + ‘node_modules/js-yaml/lib/js-yaml’,

Then I included this in my js file as
define([
‘js-yaml’,

Still i see this error,

yaml-lint.js:22 Error: window.jsyaml not defined, CodeMirror YAML linting cannot run.

Kindly let me know how to resolve this.